# Blender freezes when using the move tool on fedora 36

Tags: tools

Often when I use the move surface tool blender freezes my entire computer for a period of time, sometimes it unfreezes and sometimes it crashes.

the computer I'm testing it on isn't very powerful, duo core, 4 threads. 7th gen i5 2.6 ghz, 8 GB DDR4 RAM and no graphics card but I don't think it's that because none of the other tools cause this problem

As far as I'm aware nothing else would be interfering with it, but it's probably a setting somewhere. Running Plasma 5 if that might have something to do with it

Comment: I'm on Fedora 36 and do not encounter such issues. Have you tried using the stock Gnome that ships with it just to test if it is indeed Plasma 5 causing the issue? Also, check System Monitor to see if a core is running at 100%. If you care to edit your post and attach the .blend file I can check it for you. https://blend-exchange.com/